# How to create a view from a table and encrypt a specific field using certificate in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I am trying to create a view from a table, where I can create a hash value of a column and then encrypt another column using a certificate on my local machine.

The code below was able to create a hash value (HASHV) successfully

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Taxid_vw] 
AS
    SELECT 
        [AccountID], 
        [Property],
        [TimeSet],
        [lee] AS EncrptID,
        HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', UPPER([Value])) AS HASHV
    FROM 
        [kdo].[Property] q
    WHERE
        q.[Property] = 'IdNumber';
```

But I am also trying to encrypt the `EncrptID` column using the public key from my certificate.

My first approach was to create a certificate from a file. But I never got past this stage because I kept getting errors

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE ID_cert
 FROM FILE = 'C:\Users\Desktop\EncryptionGDPRCert.cer';
```

Error after running the above code

> Msg 15208, Level 16, State 19, Line 38
> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.

Any assist will help a great deal. Also, open to other approaches to encrypting using certificate

Comment: Does the service account have access to the Users directory? It usually doesn't. The error is likely telling you the problem, and it doesn't have access to the file. Put it somewhere the service account can access it (not the user Desktop's (an odd name for a user) directory).

Comment: @ThomA Many thanks for. Pls can you suggest a default location where service account can access files so I can store it there

Comment: Store it in the same place as database files for example

Comment: Once you've done that: hashing and encrypting are two completely different things. To encrypt, use the `ENCRYPTBYCERT` function. But certificates are slow, so you should instead use a symmetric key (which you can *protect* using your certificate or various other means). Once you created your symmetric key, you can `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` and then use `ENCRYPTBYKEY`